# Display posts on Wordpress for custom post type query

Tags: post, pagination, wordpress

I am having a few issues with displaying more than 10 posts of a particular post type.  The code I have currently is:

```
<?php get_header();
$ppp = ( !is_paged() ) ? '10' : '15';
$ofs = ( get_query_var('paged') != 0 ) ? ( ( get_query_var('paged') - 1 ) * 15 ) - 5 : 0;
// WP_Query arguments
$args = array (
    'post_type'              => array( 'book' ),
    'pagination'             => true,
    'paged'                  => get_query_var('paged'),
    'posts_per_page'         => $ppp,
    'offset'                 => $ofs,
    'ignore_sticky_posts'    => false,
);

// The Query
$query = new WP_Query( $args ); ?>
    <section class="books <?php if(get_query_var('paged') == 0){ echo 'first-page'; } else { echo 'next-page'; } ?>">
      <?php if ($query->have_posts()) : while ($query->have_posts()) : $query->the_post(); ?>
      <?php $fImg = wp_get_attachment_image_src( get_post_thumbnail_id( get_the_ID() ), 'large' ); $fi = $fImg[0]; ?>
      <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" class="grid-item-story" style="background-image: url('<?php echo $fi; ?>');">
        <article <?php post_class(); ?> id="book-<?php the_ID(); ?>">
          <div class="book-item-wrap">
            <div class="book-item-inner">
              <div class="book-item-content">
                <div class="book-item-content-inner">
                  <p class="published-date"><?php the_time('M j, Y'); ?></p>
                  <?php if ($query->current_post == 0 && !is_paged() ) { ?>
                    <h1><?php the_title(); ?></h1>
                  <?php } else { ?>
                    <h1><?php echo getBookTitle(get_the_title()); ?></h1>
                  <?php } ?>
                  <div><span class="button">Read</span></div>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </article>
      </a>
      <?php endwhile; endif; ?>
      <div class="clear"></div>
      <div class="navigation">
        <div class="next-posts"><?php next_posts_link('&laquo; Older Entries') ?></div>
        <div class="prev-posts"><?php previous_posts_link('Newer Entries &raquo;') ?></div>
      </div>
    </section>
<?php get_footer(); ?>
```

This is the full code of my `front-page.php` file. On my first page, there will be 10 posts.  On every subsequent page, there will be 15.  This is because my posts are displayed in five rows of three posts per row, except on the first page where the first post is two "posts" wide and three "posts" tall.  There are 50 posts in total for this post type.

Because of this, there should be only four pages:

1. Posts 1 - 10
2. Posts 11 - 25
3. Posts 26 - 40
4. Posts 41 - 50

However, the next / previous links are appearing on page 4, meaning there is a link to a page 5 which does not have any content.  <del>In addition, the offset doesn't seem to work, meaning page 4 displays five posts and not ten.</del> (Fixed by changing `!is_paged()` to `get_query_var('paged') != 0`)  I've added a formula to calculate the offset to see if that would fix it, which it doesn't, even though it does give the correct position when I echo it elsewhere.  I have tried the workaround listed on the WP_Query page in the Codex (correcting for the `found_posts` issue), but nothing seems to remove that fifth page.  Even if I manually set the number of posts to 15 for every page, there is still a fifth page.  I've tried `WP_Query` and `get_posts()`, and neither work.  Is there something I have missed?

Comment: Please post the code from nav.php. Where are you running this code? From an archive-{POST TYPE} template file?

Comment: Updated with full code. The code is running from my `front-page.php` template file.

Comment: If this is a static frontpage, how is your pagination working. You do not pass your custom query to `next_posts_link)`, so `next_posts_link` is relying on the main query. The main query on a static front page can only have one page. If there are more, you have a filter somewhere that is interfering with the main query object, or something on the page is using `query_posts` under the hood. Also, `pagination` is not a valid parameter, so you can remove that

Comment: From what I can see on the codex, there are only two variables to be used with `next_posts_link` - the link text and the maximum number of pages - so I can't pass anything else into it. I have changed the link to account for the maximum number of pages using `$query->max_num_pages`, and then added another six posts.  Posts 51 to 55 would appear on page 4 and post 56 on page 5. Now, I can see links to up to page 4, which solved my original query, but I've lost links to page 5. It's exactly the same regardless of whether I am using my `front-page.php` or my `archive-{POST TYPE}.php` file.

Comment: Actually, this does give me an idea ... I could try to force the maximum number of pages and use that as the second variable.

Comment: @PieterGoosen Thanks to your comment, I found a fix. I just had to manually set the maximum number of pages. I've posted my solution below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to Pieter's comment, I have been able to find a fix.  According to the codex page, I can set the maximum number of pages to display.  It just became a simple matter of manually setting that number.

In the `<?php ?>` tag for my `next_posts_link` function, just before I called the function, I added these two lines of code:

```
// Get the total number of posts found
$pc = $query->found_posts;
// Check if $pc is less than 11.
// If so, delete 10 from $pc (for the posts on the first page), then divide it by 15 (for the posts on other pages).
// Add 1 to account for the first page.
// Otherwise, return 1, because there will only be one page.
$mnp = ( $pc < 11 ) ? 1 : ceil( ( $pc - 10 ) / 15 ) + 1;
```

Comments have been added for your benefit; they aren't included in my file. Although I probably should add them.  Testing it by adding one too many posts to cleanly fit on a page has shown it works.  It probably doesn't look pretty, but it works, so I'm not complaining.